# Get array from database to json_encode

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to show an array like this (show `id_supplier` and `nama_supplier`)

```
{"1":"PT Kesatu","2":"PT Kedua","3":"PT Ketiga","4":"PT Keempat"}
```

from `supplier` table. I've used the code below:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id_supplier, nama_supplier FROM supplier ORDER BY nama_supplier");  
$supplier = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
$supplier = $row;
}
echo json_encode($supplier);
```

but it's just showing me 1 record, and the results are like this

```
{"id_supplier":"5","nama_supplier":"PT Unggas Makmur"}
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
$supplier[] = $row; // not only $supplier - [] will automatically increment the index
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[]` array.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id_supplier, nama_supplier FROM supplier ORDER BY nama_supplier");  
$supplier = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
$supplier[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($supplier);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[]` array:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id_supplier, nama_supplier FROM supplier ORDER BY nama_supplier");  
$supplier = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
$supplier[] = $row; // not only $supplier ,but [] will increment, and get all the values
}
echo json_encode($supplier);
```

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, I guess you didn't checked. Both answers were given almost at the same time, with nil time difference. You should have first watched it, before taking any action

Comment: Unfortunately, i did 'checked' ... although noone can see it now, both other answers came togethers and yours 6 minutes later.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, it was just a difference of 2-3 min that I checked yesterday. But if you feel so I can't do anything